# Get list of all paginated URL's from links in txt file in python requests

Tags: python, list, function, python-requests

Hi Guys Define a Function to Get list of all paginated URLs at bottom from links in txt file in python.

Here is an example of what i need done.

Input link

```
http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/
```

Desired Output

```
www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=2
www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=3
www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=4
www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=5
www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=6
www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=7
www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=8
www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=9
```

so on to any limit each Input Url have.

This is the function i written so far but its not working i am not good with Python either .

```
import requests
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy import Selector as Se
import urllib2


lists = open("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\\3.txt","r")
read_list = lists.read()
line = read_list.split("\n")


def get_links(line):
    for each in line:
        r = requests.get(each)
        sel = Se(text=r.text, type="html")
        next_ = sel.xpath('//a[@class="next sprite"]//@href').extract()
        for next_1 in next_:
            next_2 = "http://www.apartmentguide.com"+next_1
            print next_2
        get_links(next_1)

get_links(line)
```

Comment: List can be found at this link - appsnic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/3.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are two ways to do this.

```
import mechanize

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import urlparse

import pprint

#-- Mechanize --
br = mechanize.Browser()

def get_links_mechanize(root):
    links = []
    br.open(root)

    for link in br.links():
        try:
            if dict(link.attrs)['class'] == 'page':
                links.append(link.absolute_url)
        except:
            pass
    return links


#-- Requests / BeautifulSoup / urlparse --
def get_links_bs(root):
    links = []
    r = requests.get(root)

    for link in BeautifulSoup(r.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_attr('href') and link.has_attr('class') and 'page' in link.get('class'):
            links.append(urlparse.urljoin(root, link.get('href')))

    return links


#with open("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\\3.txt","r") as f:
#    for root in f:
#        links = get_links(root) 
#        # <Do something with links>
root = 'http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/'

print "Mech:"
pprint.pprint( get_links_mechanize(root) )
print "Requests/BS4/urlparse:"
pprint.pprint( get_links_bs(root) )
```

One uses `mechanize` -- it's a bit smarter with URLs but it's a lot slower and may be overkill depending on what else you're doing.

The other uses `requests` to fetch the page (urllib2 would suffice), `BeautifulSoup` to parse the markup and `urlparse` to form absolute URLs from the relative URLs in the page you listed.

Note that both of these functions return the following list:

```
['http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=2',
 'http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=3',
 'http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=4',
 'http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=5',
 'http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=2',
 'http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=3',
 'http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=4',
 'http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/?page=5']
```

which has duplicates.  You can get rid of the duplicates by changing

```
return links
```

to

```
return list(set(links))
```

for whatever method you choose.

**EDIT:**

I noticed that the above functions only returned the links to pages 2-5, and you'd have to navigate those pages to see that there were in fact 10 pages.

A completely different approach would be to scrape the "root" page for number of results, then predict how many pages that would result in, then build links from that.

Since there are 20 results per page, figuring out how many pages is straightforward, consider:

```
import requests, re, math, pprint

def scrape_results(root):
    links = []
    r = requests.get(root)

    mat = re.search(r'We have (\d+) apartments for rent', r.text)
    num_results = int(mat.group(1))                     # 182 at the moment
    num_pages = int(math.ceil(num_results/20.0))        # ceil(182/20) => 10

    # Construct links for pages 1-10
    for i in range(num_pages):
        links.append("%s?page=%d" % (root, (i+1)))

    return links

pprint.pprint(scrape_results(root))
```

This will be the fastest method of the 3, but possibly more error prone.

**EDIT 2**:

Maybe something like:

```
import re, math, pprint
import requests, urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

def get_pages(root):
    links = []
    r = requests.get(root)

    mat = re.search(r'We have (\d+) apartments for rent', r.text)
    num_results = int(mat.group(1))                     # 182 at the moment
    num_pages = int(math.ceil(num_results/20.0))        # ceil(182/20) => 10

    # Construct links for pages 1-10
    for i in range(num_pages):
        links.append("%s?page=%d" % (root, (i+1)))

    return links

def get_listings(page):
    links = []
    r = requests.get(page)

    for link in BeautifulSoup(r.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_attr('href') and link.has_attr('data-listingid') and 'name' in link.get('class'):
            links.append(urlparse.urljoin(root, link.get('href')))

    return links

root='http://www.apartmentguide.com/apartments/Alabama/Hartselle/'
listings = []
for page in get_pages(root):
    listings += get_listings(page)

pprint.pprint(listings)
print(len(listings))
```

Comment: Thank you Edwards, the 3rd one using math works. Actually i am after each of those 20 links that are found on each page using pagination . isn't there are any possibility using mechanize OR bs4 to follow each pagination in each links & extract 20 listings each page ?

Comment: I made another edit ("EDIT 2") -- maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks Edward, I don't know but for some reason the code object is not working.
'Doctype' object has no attribute 'has_attr'

I have bs4

Answer (score 0):

With Re i was unsure ,so tried xpath.

```
links = open("C:\Users\ssamant\Desktop\Anida\Phase_II\Apartmentfinder\\2.txt","r")
read_list = links.read()
line = read_list.split("\n")

for each in line:
    lines = []
    r = requests.get(each)
    sel = Selector(text=r.text,type="html")
    mat = sel.xpath('//h1//strong/text()').extract()
    mat = str(mat)
    mat1 = mat.replace(" apartments for rent']","")
    mat2 = mat1.replace("[u'","")
    mat3 = int(mat2)
    num_pages = int(math.ceil(mat3/20.0))
    for i in range(num_pages):
        lines.append("%s/Page%d" % (each, (i+1)))
    with open('C:\Users\ssamant\Desktop\Anida\Phase_II\Apartmentfinder\\test.csv', 'ab') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for val in lines:
            writer.writerow([val])
```